# How can I set the event property pageX/Y

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events

I am trying to create a WheelEvent and for some reason, I can't set the pageX/Y properties of the event.

```js
const mouseDownEvent = new WheelEvent('wheel', {
        clientX: event.clientX,
        clientY: event.clientY,
        deltaX: event.deltaX,
        deltaY: event.deltaY,
        deltaZ: event.deltaZ,
        screenX: event.screenX + 957,
        screenY: event.screenY,
        pageX: 1000,
        pageY: 1000,
        deltaMode: event.deltaMode,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      });
```

It appears that the pageX/Y values of the mouse are used. 
Any idea how to fix this?

[image: Resulting Image]

Comment: It looks like these properties are getting set from the pointing device: https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-wheel-types. Can this be changed??

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging I found out that the sourceCapabilities property is required.

```js
const scrollEvent = new WheelEvent('wheel', {
        deltaX: event.deltaX,
        deltaY: event.deltaY,
        deltaZ: event.deltaZ,
        deltaMode: event.deltaMode,
        clientX: event.clientX + 1000,
        clientY: event.clientY,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        /* eslint-disable no-undef */ // new feature
        sourceCapabilities: new InputDeviceCapabilities(),
      });
```